# Function to read and parse data mixes results from different tables with different keys in React

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, react-hooks

- I am trying to render 2 tables in the same page which get the data from 2 diffrent csv files
- they use the same function to read and parse the data
- If I load this 2 components in the same page they will mix the data and render some of the data from the second table on the first one

How do I stop the render of the "BMS table" as soon as I get all the correct values?

How do I avoid having data from the "Battery Specifications table" on the "BMS table"?

The function to get the data is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {Numbatt} from './ReadBattInfo';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const values = [];

function GetData(props) {
    
    const [batt, setBatt] = useState(0);
    from(Numbatt()).subscribe(x => setBatt(x)); -- > Comes from another function that monitors the number of batteries connected. Can be replaced by a constant number.
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try{
                for (let i = 0; i < batt; i++) {
                    let csvfile = './data/batt' + (i) + '/' + props.file;
                    await d3.csv(csvfile).then((data) => {
                      let temp=[];
                      data.map((d) => {
                        temp.push(d.value);
                        return () => undefined;
                      });
                      values[i] = temp.slice(props.slice);
                    });
                };
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            };
        };
        fetchData()
      }, [batt]);

    return({loading, values})
}

export default GetData
```

BMS render function

```
const file = 'bmsfault.csv';
const slice = -6;

function BMS() {
    const {loading, values} = GetData({file, slice});
    console.log(values);

    return (
        <>
        <div className="w3-main w3-panel" style={{marginLeft:"300px"}}>
        <div className="w3-row-padding" style={{margin: 0 -16+"px"}}>
            <div>
                <h5>BMS - Battery Managment System</h5>
                {loading && <div>LOADING...</div>}
                {!loading && values.map((value, i) => {
                    return (
                        <table key={'bms'+i} className="w3-table w3-border w3-white w3-half">
                            <thead className="w3-blue">
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th><i>Battery {i+1} </i></th>
                                    <th>Parameters</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBolt} /></td>
                                    <td>Charge MOS State</td>
                                    <td><i>{value[0]}</i></td>
                                </tr>
```

BattSpecs render function

```
const file = 'batt_param.csv'
const slice = -6;

function BatterySpecs() {
    const {loading, values} = GetData({file, slice});

  return (
    <>
    <div className="w3-container w3-panel w3-main" style={{marginLeft:"300px"}}>
      <div className="w3-row-padding" style={{margin:0 -16+"px"}}>
      <div>
        <h5>Battery Specifications</h5>
        {loading && <div>LOADING...</div>}
        {!loading && values.map((value, i) => {
            return (
                <table key={'battspec'+i} className="w3-table w3-border w3-white w3-half">
                    <thead className="w3-blue">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th><i>Battery {i+1} </i></th>
                            <th>Values</th>
                        </tr>
```

- I made sure I gave different keys to the html elements but I think somehow the variable "values" is rendered on the BMS table even when the GetData function is supposed to be reading the batt_param.csv

Solution:

```
function GetData(props) {
    const [data,setData] = useState([]); // saving values nested array inside the function.
    const [batt, setBatt] = useState(0);
    from(Numbatt()).subscribe(x => setBatt(x));
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        const values = [];
        const temp = [];
        setLoading(true);
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try{
                for (let i = 0; i < batt; i++) {
                    let csvfile = './sftp/000000004b11cf51/data/batt' + (i) + '/' + props.file;
                    await d3.csv(csvfile).then((data) => {
                      data.map((d) => {
                        temp.push(d.value);
                        return () => undefined;
                      });
                      values[i] = temp.slice(props.slice);
                    });
                    if (i===batt-1){
                      setLoading(false);
                    }
                };
                setData(values); // saving values array to data
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            };
        };
        fetchData()
      }, [batt]);
      console.log(data);
```

Comment: `return () => undefined` - what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Why is `values` outside the scope of your custom hook?  (Which should be named something like `useData` by convention.)  If you're observing concurrency issues, that's *probably* the culprit since both calls to `GetData` would be modifying the same array.  Overall this probably (1) shouldn't be a hook, but just a normal function and most certainly (2) shouldn't be modifying anything outside of its own scope.

Comment: That was it David! I need to add values in the function and the value will belong only to the function that called it.